# Running commands in bash script in parallel with loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script where I start a packet capture with `tshark` and then check whether the user has submitted an input text file.
If there is a file present, I need to run a command for every item in the file through a loop (while `tshark` is running); else continue running `tshark`.
I would also like some way to stop `tshark` with user input such as a letter.

Code snippet:

```
echo "Starting tshark..."
sleep 2
tshark -i ${iface} &>/dev/null 
tshark_pid=$!

# if devices aren't provided (such as in case of new devices, start capturing directly)
if [ -z "$targets" ]; then
        echo "No target list provided."
else
        for i in $targets; do
                echo "Attempting to deauthenticate $i..."
                sudo aireplay-ng -0 $number -a $ap -c $i $iface$mon
        done
fi
```

What happens here is that `tshark` starts, and only when I quit it using `Ctrl+c` does it move on to the `if` statement and subsequent loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a & at the end of command executes the command in a new sub process. Mind you won't be able to kill it with ctlr + c

example:
`firefox`
will block the shell
`firefox &` will not block shell

Comment: Okay so this works since I am redirecting the output of the command to a file. However, using ```tshark &>/dev/null/``` did not run the loop but instead waited for ```tshark``` to end / be interrupted. Any idea what the problem could be there?

Comment: `&>`  means redirect both stderr and stdout. and the file `/dev/null` is like a black whole. `&>/dev/null/` means I don't care about the output. I was thinking of `tshark -i ${iface} &>/dev/null &`

Comment: Oh that makes more sense, thanks. I'd assumed that using ```&>/dev/null/``` did not need me to add another ```&``` at the end of the command.

Comment: I'd seen a blog post saying that ```&>/dev/null``` would push the process to the background and also redirect output to null. I also came across another SO post which says the same. So not really sure why that didn't work for me.